# Django Chartit Scatterplot Will Not Display

Tags: jquery, python, django, highcharts, scatter-plot

I'm building a simple web application that accepts information from a form, uses that information to query data from an API, and then returns relevant data from the API's response in a dataframe.

The dataframe renders as expected. However, in addition to the dataframe, I'd like to return a scatterplot using two relevant columns of the dataframe. This is where I run into issues. I thought that I was following the correct steps, but I'm obviously missing something:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
.
.
'django.contrib.admin',
'chartit',
)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class results2(models.Model):
  item_1 = models.IntegerField()
  item_2 = models.IntegerField()
  item_3 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  item_4 = models.IntegerField()
  item_5 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  .
  .
  item_19 = models.IntegerField()
  item_20 = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from blog.models import SearchForm, results2
from numpy import *
from pandas import *
from chartit import DataPool, Chart

results = results2()

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            .
            . #DO SOME STUFF
            .
            final_frame.reset_index(drop="True")

            for i in range(1,len(final_frame),1):
                results.item_1 = int32(output[0])
                results.item_2 = int32(final_frame.loc[i,['item_2']])
                results.item_3 = str(final_frame.loc[i,['item_3']])
                results.item_4 = int32(final_frame.loc[i,['item_4']])
                results.item_5 = str(final_frame.loc[i,['item_5']])
                .
                .
                results.item_19 = int32(final_frame.loc[i,['item_19']])
                results.item_20 = int32(final_frame.loc[i,['item_20']])
                results.save()

            final_frame = final_frame.loc[:,['item_2','item_3','item_4','item_5','item_6','item_7','item_8','item_9','item_10','item_11','item_12','item_13']]            
            return HttpResponse(final_frame.to_html(), 'results.html')
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})

def scatter_cart_view(request):
    scatterdata = DataPool(
                    series = 
                        [{'options': {
                            'source': results2.objects.all()},
                          'terms': [
                            'item_4',
                            'item_5']}])  

    cht = Chart(
            datasource = scatterdata, 
            series_options = 
                [{'options':{
                        'type': 'scatter'},
                  'terms':[
                          'item_4',
                          'item_5']
                          }],
            chart_options = 
                {'title':{
                    'text': 'Scatter Title'},
                'xAxis': {
                        'title': {
                                'text': 'Axis Title'}}})

    return render_to_response('results.html', {'scatterchart':cht})
```

results.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{scatterchart|load_charts:"container"}}
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="container"></div>
    <div id ="content">{{% final_frame %}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not receive any error messages; the chart simply does not display. At some point I'll need to filter model columns so that only data relevant to the query are plotted, but that shouldn't be a factor here. Am I not saving the data correctly? Do I need multiple views? Am I not bringing in JQuery and Highcharts properly? I'm at a loss here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: At the beginning remove one jquery, because you load it twice. Secondly in the console (developer tools in chrome) you are ensured that you have no errors?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed both JQuery scripts (one at a time), and that had no impact on the result. It does not appear that errors are present.

Comment: Have you live demo of your chart?